# What is the use of WITH RETURN clause in DB2?

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports, db2

I see several stored procedures in this application I am now responsible for, some of which use this syntax for cursors:

```
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
```

...and others that use this syntax for cursors:

```
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
```

All of these stored procedures are used by Crystal Reports 11.
Please explain to me, what is the difference between these two?  They both return rows to Crystal Reports successfully.  I am trying to optimize this one stored procedure and I wasn't sure what this clause even does.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in the manual?

Given that you're returning results to an external client,  the WITH RETURN TO CLIENT would be a better choice.

Comment: I did look in the manual and several other links, but I still do not see a distinction or I am just not understanding.  I am returning results to a client, but both cursors work, so I'm wondering what's the difference?

Comment: what platform?  LUW, IBM i, or z/OS?  From what I can see, if LUW you shouldn't be seeing the results set without the WITH RETURN.  Whereas on IBM i, if using a prepared statement, the WITH RETURN is the default.  I didn't look at z/OS.

Comment: It's on AIX, is that LUW?

Comment: From your comment, it seems that "with return" may be the default, implied clause anyway.  So it may just be optional and operate the same either way?

Comment: Yes, AIX is the U in LUW.  According to the docs, WITHOUT RETURN is the default and unlike the IBM i, the LUW docs don't have an exception for prepared statements.  Are you using a prepared statement or a static?  ie. DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR MYSTATEMENT vs. DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM TBL.